# Why ionic cordova build for iOS is failed with error

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I have problem with ionic cordova build for iOS.

When I use command:

```
ionic cordova build android -dev
```

build ends successful (sometimes only the second time), but build for ios always ends with this error:

```
cat: no paths given
[xmldom error]  invalid doc source 
@#[line:0,col:undefined]
Error: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios --debug (exit code 1).
```

I'm don't have any idea where is a problem.

My ionic info:

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 5.1.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.4 Build version 9F1027a
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Probably you have an error in your code where you use documentElement, try to remove it

Comment: It's angular project, so code is generate to native platforms. In project files documentElement doesn't exist. I must add that build ios code its worked - I can compile it in Xcode and install/run on my device. This error isn't problem on local MacBook, but builds must be run on server (jenkins).